# Eclipse RCP propertychangelistener usage, the proper way?

Tags: eclipse, rcp, propertychangelistener

I'm working on an editor to make changes to a list of emf objects. What I want is every time I modify those emf objects, my editor is to be refreshed to reflect the changes.

The approach I tried before was having a wrapper object over the said emf object (because I don't know how I can or should modify the emf-generated source code) to contain the editor needs to be refresh. The changes will be made on top of that wrapper object, and propertychangelistener is to be dispatched after emf object have been changed. However this solution is very ugly because:

- Each object will need to obtain the reference to the editor itself, introducing a reference dependency
- Having a separate overlay object like that introduces complication into maintaining the code

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I think of adding binding framework to handle model object changes

You may want to look at following tutorial as a starting point.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDataBinding/article.html

Comment: I read that one, but I'm not sure if the case would be similar. The author binds an object to a label, while what I have is a list of objects display on the table. While it would make sense if changing the list of object being displayed will trigger an update on the viewer, I don't see how editing just 1 row in the table will trigger the refresh.

Comment: You can bind Table input with ListObservable, it triggers refresh when new element is added/removed to/from the List. Editing cell also you can use Observables to bind the cell value with CellEditor

Comment: sounds like what I need. I haven't got time to try it out yet, but thanks for your answer anyway :)